# I'm running randomForest on my dataset - MYDATA

Tags: r

I'm running randomForest my dataset, see below structure below:

```
str(MYDATA)
'data.frame':   55377 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ ï..Archive_Date: Factor w/ 12 levels "20/12/2018","26/04/2018",..: 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ Hospital_Group : Factor w/ 7 levels "Children's Hospital Group",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Group.ID       : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Hospital_HIPE  : int  940 940 940 940 940 940 940 940 940 940 ...
 $ Hospital_Name  : Factor w/ 44 levels "Bantry General Hospital",..: 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 ...
 $ Specialty_HIPE : int  0 0 400 400 600 600 600 600 600 600 ...
 $ Specialty_Name : Factor w/ 53 levels "Anaesthetics",..: 51 51 9 9 32 32 32 32 32 32 ...
 $ Case_Type      : Factor w/ 2 levels "Day Case","Inpatient": 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ Adult_Child    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Adult","Child": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Age_Profile    : Factor w/ 3 levels "0-15","16-64",..: 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Time_Bands     : num  7.5 10.5 4.5 13.5 1.5 4.5 7.5 10.5 13.5 1.5 ...
 $ Total          : int  1 1 1 1 14 2 1 2 2 44
```

When I call the confusion matrix I get the following error:

```
rf <- predict(forest, MyDATA_Test, type = "class")
> confusionMatrix(rf, MyDATA_Test$Time_Bands, positive = "Yes")
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

How do I solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

randomForest is particular about having the same levels for factor variables.  We can change the `levels` of the test dataset to have the same levels as train.

```
# get the column names of factor columns
nm1 <- names(which(sapply(MYDATA, is.factor)))
#  get the levels of subset of columns in a `list`
lst1 <- lapply(MYDATA[nm1], levels)

# use Map to assign the `levels` of 'MyData_Test' with the train column levels
MYDATA_Test[nm1] <- Map(`levels<-`, MyDATA_Test[nm1], lst1)
```

NOTE: Assuming that there are no new levels in test dataset (which is not present in train).